# Don't allow convert to future year moment.js

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I'm using moment.js to handle my date time values in my web application. I'm using follow format: `DD.MM.YYYY` for example `29.09.2016`. Now I have some input fields, where I can type in the day of birth of a person. When I type a short year between 62 and 99, it converts it like this for example: `input` = `29.09.82` it converts it after pressing tab to `29.09.2082` (puts 20 befor the 82). When I write a short year between 00 and 62 in converts it like this example: `input` = `29.09.55` would be converted to `29.09.1955` (puts 19 before the 55). So the first range will be convertet to a year in the 21th century and the second range would be convertet to a year in the 20th century (this seems to be default, I don't know why). Now I would like to prevent converting to a year, which is in the future (so not more than 2016, and just 2016 when the short year is 16). How can I do this? At this moment I have something like this:

```
if(value.isValid() && isDayOfBirth) {
    value.format(myFormat);
}
```

Is there a way to do this or to check it? I didn't found anything in the http://momentjs.com/docs/. Thanks.

Comment: The editor of stackoverflow has some problems, I couldn't add the whole text?!? When I edit my question and add 2 words it shows me in the preshow but don't save it correct.....

Comment: how do you prepare the date object from the input? this `29.09.82` format is not supported by moment

Comment: @JaganathanBantheswaran I write it into my input (as string), than I get it to my controller and convert it to my format 'DD.MM.YYYY' and get the result of 29.09.2082... I don't know how and why I just use format() and the format I wrote above... The converting is automaticlly than..

Comment: @JaganathanBantheswaran and look here: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/ two digit year is possible..

Comment: I believe it's an issue with moment.js. Logged an issue on behalf of you. https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3473

Comment: Using sort years like 55 or 82 with moment format is the problem i think. Why cant you use 4 digit years like 2055, 2082 and try to restrict the future year?

Comment: @JaganathanBantheswaran Thanks for the issue... I can't our costumers require to type just a short year (because they are faster) for a day of birth and then let it convert in the past, because a year in the future doesn't really make sense for a day of birth... so I try to resolve their requirements...

Comment: @JaganathanBantheswaran look at the answer which I marked as correct. It works perfect! Cheers

Comment: I liked the hack for your problem. But still moment has issues on the shorten year formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.
You take the current year and check if the parsed year is greater than that.
If so, you subtract 100 years (bringing you back to 20th century).

```
var now = moment(),
    year = now.year(); //Get current year

if (parsedDate.year() > year) {
  parsedDate.subtract(100, "year");
}
```